# How to pass controller action in Jquery AJAX Call in Oxid eSHOP

Tags: oxid

I am working on Jquery AJAX in OXID eSHOP.

I want to pass proper action (function) name in AJAX url parameter.

Below is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            variable: value
        },
        url: "",
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
```

I want to call one function in url parameter.

But don't know how to pass its value in url paramaeter.

Anyone knows then please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should include function name as URL parameter, just like the shop does it in most situations:
http://your-shop.com/index.php?cl=controller&fnc=functionname